Law for simulation of solar system
I heard that from simulations we know that the solar system is stable for the next 400-10000 years. And I am wondering, if you want to simulate the solar system, which equations do you take? Normally one would say Newtons gravitational law, but for this large time scales, Mercury perihelion shift should have an effect. No? Full GR calculations is also not possible (we barely can simulate the 2 body problem in GR). So is there a 'GR' correction term-approximation to Newtons law?
Or does one just ignore this problem in practise.

This Dr. Becky video might help - Why the Earth exists because of Saturn | Migration of Planets
